# login block - drupal

Tags: drupal, authentication

Is it possible in drupal to delete the login block? And how do I login in drupal to the adminestrator user, if I delete the login block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to delete the login block. Look for blocks in the admin pages (/admin/build/block) and make it inactive.

To login, simply go to http://example.com/user/login

Answer (score 0):

Please do following steps:

```html
1.Login as admin

2.Go to 'base_url/admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure

3.find 'REGION SETTINGS' area,select 'none' based on your theme.

4.click save block
```