# How do I remove the user registration/login form?

Tags: drupal

My website doesn't need the user login functionality. Only some users need to post new nodes.

How do I remove the user registration and the login forms in Drupal?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4977759/1741542

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While it's technically possible to remove the login functionality, you shouldn't, because then your administrator could never log onto the site.

In order to remove the register functionality, you simply need to browse to `admin/user/settings` (for Drupal 6) or `admin/config/people/accounts` (for Drupal 7) and select the the "Only site administrators can create new user accounts" option.

Comment: Thanks! In Drupal 7 admin page, is there any other way to remove the display login in home page? Or I need to edit the theme and remove the login in template file?

Comment: To remove the login link from the home page, you should be able to remove the user block via admin/structure/block.

Comment: The link is still the same in Drupal 9 (`admin/config/people/accounts`)

Answer (score 16):

While jhedstrom answer does work, I particuarly find that it doesn't fully address the issue.

Here's  a simple way to remove the login form from the site on Drupal 7.

First, let's create a new **simple page** called **Admin**. Simply go to Content - Add Content - Basic Page. Enter whatever details you'd like such as title, body, etc. just make sure that under **URL path settings** you specify a common alias for adminstration, I used **admin**.

Second step, let's make sure that the login form only shows on the **admin** page we just created. Navigate to Structure - Blocks - User login (note tat the block name may vary from installation to installation), and hit **Configure**. Under **Visibility settings** select the option **Only the listed pages** so that the block only shows for the pages you specify on the input, and enter the alias you set on the step above (**admin**).

Finally, let's ensure that only administrators can create accounts, by following jhedstrom's suggestion. Go to Configuration - People - Account settings, then under **Registration and cancellation**, ensure that the box for **Administrators Only** is selected for the **Who can register accounts?** option.

I think this is a much nicer and detailed approach to ensure that the login form isn't displayed, considering you don't need people creating accounts on your site.

Comment: +1, this is the only answer that actually solves the problem at hand.

Comment: Agree with @MarcClaesen .. The answer given as correct is the "how do you stop this from happening - well just switch it off" answer whereas daniel's answer is definitely the correct one. Flagged for moderator input.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it using hook_menu(), move login page in any other suitable for administrative needs place

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the forms all together. In a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['#access'] = FALSE;
    break;
  }
}
```

Depending on your needs, you can either create a custom page and set the login block there, so you and other administrators can login, or install [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module to allow visitors to login and register new accounts only through social media 3rd parties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Disable Login Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_login) module to disable the login page completely for the general public. Only the webmaster or site admins who have access to a secret key/value pair will be able to access the login page. Everybody else will get access denied at user/login page. This will work in Drupal 8 and Drupal 9.