# How to Disable the CreateNew Account Tab in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, user-registration

How do i disable the Create New Account Tab in Drupal 7. I have created a new an alternative registration form using drupal username and password form but i do not want the create new account tab displayed.How can i do thisin drupal 7?

Answer (score 3):

[This has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352381/how-to-remove-user-register-login-in-drupal) 
You can do in from the drupal's 7 backoffice in `admin/config/people/accounts` section whitout programming skills. Then in `"Registration and cancellation > Who can register accounts?` " section, choose "`Administrators only`"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want hook_menu_alter: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7

You can just set the permissions to false or delete the whole menu entry. Or since you build your own you can just point the callback to your own page.

Comment: Thanks Danielson for the feedback. I am relatively new to Programming. What file do i need to modify in drupal to achieve the result. The alternative Registration form i use still use Drupal Login.

Comment: @user1611295 This is drupal. You don't modify existing files to change functionality you create new modules and override the functionality with hooks. That way you don't need to hack the core system. Not enough room to explain here. Check out the book pro drupal 7 development http://www.amazon.com/Drupal-Development-Experts-Voice-Source/dp/1430228385/ref=dp_ob_title_bk